# ASP.Net Core MVC - Client-side validation for custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous versions of the MVC framework custom validation would be achieved through implementing `IClientValidatable` and the `GetClientValidationRules` method.

However in ASP.Net Core MVC [we do not have this interface](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IClientValidatable), although we do have `IClientModelValidator` which a defining a very similar method.  The implementation of which never gets called however.

So - how do we implement client-side validation for a custom attribute in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `IClientModelValidator` is in fact the right interface. I've made a contrived sample implementation below.

### Attribute

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class CannotBeRedAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var message = value as string;
        return message?.ToUpper() == "RED";
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-cannotbered", errorMessage);
    }

    private bool MergeAttribute(
        IDictionary<string, string> attributes,
        string key,
        string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Model

```cs
public class ContactModel
{
    [CannotBeRed(ErrorMessage = "Red is not allowed!")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```html
@model WebApplication.Models.ContactModel

<form asp-action="Contact" method="post">
    <label asp-for="Message"></label>
    <input asp-for="Message" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Message"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.validator.addMethod("cannotbered",
            function (value, element, parameters) {
                return value.toUpperCase() !== "RED";
            });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("cannotbered", [], function (options) {
            options.rules.cannotbered = {};
            options.messages["cannotbered"] = options.message;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: I have done exactly as shown by you in the example. but its not working, it is not showing the message returned by GetClientValidationRules. Instead showing the default required message ?

Comment: @Rohit The custom attribute in my example will only show an error if you type in the word "red" in the input box.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's working. However, how can I return my custom message from GetClientValidationRules method. I do not want specify on model attribute like `[CannotBeRed(ErrorMessage = "Not red!")]`

Comment: I have written a class from where I am getting custom error messages which I want to use in 'GetClientValidationRules' method. If I do so like `yield return new ModelClientValidationRule(
                "cannotbered",
                FormatErrorMessage(MyClass.GetCustomMessage('somekey'));` , instead it is showing the default Required field message as 'The message field is required'. Can you please help on this ?

Comment: @Rohit Remove the `[Required]` attribute from the `Message` property in my example. That's what's giving you the default required message. As far as pulling down a custom message, I would recommend [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24177263/4270650). It should still be valid for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Its working fine ! Also, can you please tell me how I can do other validation like comparison, length, currency,numeric validation ? Do I need to right different rules for each validation and what changes needs to be done in jQuery.

Comment: I have done sample password comparison like `public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            
            var modelClientValidationEqualToRule = new ModelClientValidationEqualToRule("Password ans confirm password do not match.", _OtherPropertyName);
            
            yield return modelClientValidationEqualToRule;
        }`

Comment: and in jQuery `$.validator.addMethod("equalto",
       function (value, element, parameters) {
           return value;

       });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('equalto', [], function (options) {
          
            options.rules.equalto = {};
            options.messages['equalto'] = options.message;
        });`  Is this a right approach ?

Comment: @Rohit I think you've reached a point where asking a new question on SO would be beneficial. I'm having a little trouble following you in these last comments, and fresh question would open it up to more folks. All that being said, there is a [CompareAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) that I've used for password comparison in the past without issue.

Comment: Can't find ModelClientValidationRule in MVC core (RC2). Anyone?

Comment: @ScottE There was a breaking change made to the interface between RC1 and RC2. See my updated answer for more information and an updated example.