# ASP.NET Core 2.0 ModelState Filter before Validation?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Can I do something like this in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

For example, I have this ViewModel:

```
public class TodoViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required !")] // <--- Required
    public int? Key { get; set; } // Is Nullable

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required !")] // <--- Required
    public int? Value { get; set; } Nullable

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required !")] // <--- Required
    public byte Type { get; set; }
}
```

In View for Example, I have this:

```
@Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post)
{ 
    @if (Model.Type == 1)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Key)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Key)
    }

    @if (Model.Type == 2)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Key)
    }
}
```

and in Action I have this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Todo(TodoViewModel model)
    {
        // My problem
        // if model.type = 1 return ModelState has error validate for Property (Value) is Required
        // and if model.type = 2 return ModelState has error validate for Property (Key) is Required
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) // <-- Here is my problem
            return View(model);
    }
```

I do not want to use @Html.HiddenFor()

To override validation for other property

I tried to use ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class TodoActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        TodoViewModel model = (TodoViewModel) context.ActionArguments["model"];

        if (model.Type == 1)
            model.Value = 0;

        if (model.Type == 2)
            model.Key = 0;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, Execute for (OnActionExecuting) is after ModelState is Validation.

Is there a specific way to do this?

I want to exclude ModelState validate for "Key" property  if  "Type" property equal 1,

and exclude ModelState validate for "Value" property  if  "Type" property equal 2

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute, for example a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequredIf]`. Or if your want to write your own refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a clear indication that you actually need **two** ViewModels. Either that or you do just a rough validation on the ViewModel and do a more detailed one in your business logic.

Of course you could write your own validation attribute (but not via `ActionFilterAttribute` but by inheriting from [ValidationAttribute (Custom Validation Attribute)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation) and putting it on the View Model instead of `[Required]`)), which will check if one is required, but this essentially just covers/hides your intent that you have two different type of models.

Validation attributes aren't there to enforce business rules, they should be kinda simple and validate if the data looks good at the first look before the business validations are applied (which may required additional checks, services or database round-trips).

But remember if you go with the custom validation attribute, there won't be any client sided validation (via JavaScript in the browser). You'd also need to implement an `AttributeAdapterBase<T>` [RequiredAttribute Example](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations/Internal/RequiredAttributeAdapter.cs).

Comment: All you need to do is have the `ValidationAttribute` implement `IClientValidatable` to get client side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Mind providing an example or reference? There's no such interface in the [ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/) repository

Comment: After adding the comment I realized it was `core-mvc` and re-tagged the question. In core its `IClientModelValidator`

Comment: An example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566836/asp-net-core-mvc-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute) although have not yet been able to find a good blog covering conditional client side validation for core (like [this one](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the IValidatableObject Interface.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class TodoViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int? Key { get; set; } 

    public int? Value { get; set; } 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required !")] 
    public byte Type { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Type == 1)
        {
            yield return
              new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "Property (Value) is Required",
                                   memberNames: new[] { "Value" });
        }
        if (Type == 2)
        {
            yield return
              new ValidationResult(errorMessage: "Property (Key) is Required",
                                   memberNames: new[] { "Key" });
        }

   }
}
```