# asp.net core 2.0 IClientModelValidator, HtmlHelpers, LambdaExpression

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, data-annotations, html-helper, jquery-inputmask

I'm working on clean client validation with **IClientModelValidator** and **customs Html Helpers** to apply css style in my app.

I found and implemented this interesting example about client validation and custom DataAnnotations.
[ASP.Net Core MVC - Client-side validation for custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566836/asp-net-core-mvc-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute)

**That's perfect when I use the default helper @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestCurrency) !**

Now I want to enable jquery-inputmask on my custom DataAnnotations. To do this I need to add some specific css class like this :

*(Yes I can just add my mask class in the custom helper, but I have like 15 helpers : VEmailBoxFor, VPasswordFor, VPhoneNumberFor... by adding the class according to a custom DataAnnotation I will be albe to use just one helper, really easier to maintain )*

```
public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
{
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
    var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-cannotbered", errorMessage);
    MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "class", "currency");
}
```

Once again when I'm using @Html.TextBoxFor(), I found the "currency" css class in the output and the client validation works as well.

```
<input class="currency" data-val="true" data-val-cannotbered="Red is not allowed!" id="TestCurrency" name="TestCurrency" type="text" value="">
```

But, the default style is not realy nice, isn't it ?

Like I said, I created helpers to fit with bootstrap. One of them looks like :

```
public static IHtmlContent VTextBoxFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression, object attributes)
```

I add all my css class and at the end I render the text box like this :

```
return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
```

**Now my problem appears :**

```
<input class=" validate form-control " data-val="true" data-val-cannotbered="Red is not allowed!" id="TestCurrency" name="TestCurrency" type="text" value="">
```

- The style looks good
- The client validation works
- **But, my class "currency" is gone**

**Can I catch the "validation"/"html" attributes from the `Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression` ?**

*Sorry for this verry long post, but It's a little bit tricky for me. I hope to be clear enough.*

Thank you all