# Should a ValidationAttribute have one error message?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

[ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a string implying there should be one error per ValidationAttribute.

Say I have some code like this:

```
[BeforeThan(nameof(EndTime), nameof(EndTime2), ErrorMessage = "StartTime should before than EndTime and EndTime2")]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
```

and an IsValid method like this:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object startTime, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var endTimePropertyValue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(EndTimePropertyName)
          .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

    if (startTime != null && startTime is DateTime
        & endTimePropertyValue != null && endTimePropertyValue is DateTime)
    {
        if ((DateTime)startTime > (DateTime)endTimePropertyValue)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

There is unobtrusive JavaScript on the client side.

Say I wanted to add more logic to say; if end date 1 is the same as end date 2 then report a different error message.

1. Create a separate attribute for this i.e. have two attributes.
2. Amend the code above somehow to return two different error messages depending on the scenario

Please remember that I am usinf obtrusive JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: You could refer to a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901736/10158551

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit need of using only `ErrorMessage` property to set error text. You can introduce additional properties indicate whether it's needed to check if dates are equal

```
public string ErrorMessage2 { get; set; }

protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object startTime, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var endTimePropertyValue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(EndTimePropertyName)
            .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

    if (startTime != null && startTime is DateTime
        & endTimePropertyValue != null && endTimePropertyValue is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime startDateTime = (DateTime)startTime;
        DateTime endDateTime = (DateTime)endTimePropertyValue;

        //if second error message is not empty we check if date are the same
        bool checkIfEqual = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage2);

        if (checkIfEqual && startDateTime == endDateTime)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage2);
        }
        else if (startDateTime > endDateTime)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Or you can discard `ErrorMessage` at all and use hardcoded strings

```
private const string StartDateBefore = "StartTime should before than EndTime and EndTime2";
private const string StartDateEqual = "StartTime is equal to EndTime";

public bool CheckIfEqual { get; set; }

protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object startTime, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var endTimePropertyValue = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(EndTimePropertyName)
            .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

    if (startTime != null && startTime is DateTime
        & endTimePropertyValue != null && endTimePropertyValue is DateTime)
    {
        DateTime startDateTime = (DateTime)startTime;
        DateTime endDateTime = (DateTime)endTimePropertyValue;

        if (CheckIfEqual && startDateTime == endDateTime)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(StartDateEqual); //error message when dates are equal
        }
        else if (startDateTime > endDateTime)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(StartDateBefore); //error message when start date is after enddate
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Usage

```
[SomeValidation(nameof(EndDate), CheckIfEqual = true)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

To make this validation attribute work with client side validation you need to implement `IClientModelValidator` interface as it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36575006/7775908).

```
public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
{
    //"beforedate" and "equaldate" will be added as custom validators
    //for unobtrusive validation
    context.Attributes.Add("data-val-beforedate", StartDateBefore);

    if (CheckIfEqual)
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-equaldate", StartDateEqual);
}
```

With this code implemented `input` will contain additional attributes with respective error messages. Now we need to implement custom validators in javascript and copy validation logic from `C#` code

```
//add "beforedate" custom validator
$.validator.addMethod("beforedate", function (value, element, parameters) {
    var startDate = new Date(value);
    var endDate = new Date($("#EndDate").val());

    //if condition is true then value considered valid
    return endDate >= startDate;
});

//add unobtrusive adapter to run "beforedate" validation
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("beforedate", [], function (options) {
    options.rules.beforedate = {};
    options.messages["beforedate"] = options.message; //save error message passed from C#
});

$.validator.addMethod("equaldate", function (value, element, parameters) {
    var startDate = new Date(value);
    var endDate = new Date($("#EndDate").val());

    return endDate.getTime() != startDate.getTime();
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("equaldate", [], function (options) {
    options.rules.equaldate = {};
    options.messages["equaldate"] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: Can you post the JQuery code as well as this is more what I am concerned about?

Comment: @w0051977 What jQuery code are interested in? Do you want to apply this logic on client side, right?

Comment: Are you able to answer my comment above before I mark the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 I'm currently studying possible solutions for asp net core with unobtrusive jquery

Comment: @w0051977 Updated my answer

Comment: I also worked on this last night and that is what I arrived at as well.  Thanks.  Do you know in what order the client side javascript runs? Is it the order the adapters are added?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, quick test has shown that adding order matters

Comment: do you know of any documentation that supports this? Thanks.

Comment: jQuery validation docs are [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), not sure if they are really good. Unobtrusive jQuery [github](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive), couldn't find official docs for it.