# HTML5 required, validation work, but message is not displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I implemented validation "required" in my "checkbox 'and it works, the" set focus "is on the field, but the validation message is not displayed!

```html
<form  asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Etapa 4 - Termos de Uso</h4>
        <h5>Para concluir a sua inscrição basta validar que você não é um robo e concordar com os termos de uso!</h5>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcgsyITAAAAAHiF8A1MGysKGUfQddq-_uzBD8ba"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8  checkbox-inline">
            <input asp-for="Aceite" required  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Para concluir a inscrição é necessário aceitar os termos de uso')"/>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Li e concordo com os termos de uso e privacidade</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8  checkbox-inline">
            <input asp-for="AceitePromocao" />
            <label asp-for="AceitePromocao"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-pull-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Aceitar e concluir" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Which property are you expecting a validation error for? All you have shown is checkboxes for `bool` properties which will never have a validation error unless a malicious user submitted a `null` value (both `true` and `false` are valid for `bool`)

Comment: want to validate if it is selected, it seems to me that is validation is working, why not select when and try to send is not sent and the setfocus is appointed to the checkbox! but the message is not displayed

Comment: Because if its not checked it has a value of `false` which is a valid value for a `bool` property so therefore no error is shown. If you want to show an error message if its left unchecked, then you can just ad a `ModelState` error when you submit and return the view. Or you can write your own `[MustBeTrue]` validation attribute that implement `IClientValidatable` to get both client and server side validation

Comment: I understand that, what is the best practice for this validation, javascript, "must be true", have a example ?

Comment: Start by looking at [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3 - PART 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) to get you started. Also [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986928/enforcing-a-models-boolean-value-to-be-true-using-data-annotations)

Comment: In case anyone else comes here wondering where the "must be true" validator is. You can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64766089/5779818

Answer (score 0):

This is because a *checkbox* required validation is not logical. A *checkbox* can always be **true or false**. It's **true** when you're checking it otherwise false.

That means it **always have a value**.