# Make checkbox required with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to show message for the user that he must accepted the terms after he submit the form if the checkbox is unchecked and submit the form if the checkbox is checked.

I have this code on my model:

```
public class UserClass
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private readonly ApplicationUserClass _auc;
public abcController(ApplicationUserClass auc)
{
    _auc = auc;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(UserClass uc)
{
    _auc.Add(uc);
    _auc.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <b>@ViewBag.message</b>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see a lot of examples, but not work. Anybody can give advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer to the following sample:

1. Create a UserViewModel to transfer data between View and controller:

   ```
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entry Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        //use custom validation method
        [CheckBoxRequired(ErrorMessage ="Please checked the items")]
        public bool IsAccepted { get; set; } 
    }
   ```
2. Add the custom validation method:

   ```
    public class CheckBoxRequired : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //get the entered value
            var student = (UserViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            //Check whether the IsAccepted is selected or not.
            if (student.IsAccepted == false)
            { 
                //if not checked the checkbox, return the error message.
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage == null ? "Please checked the checkbox" : ErrorMessage); 
            }
            return  ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Create the Action methods to create user and use the UserViewModel to transfer data between View and Controller.

   ```
        public IActionResult CreateUser()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //after validation success, create a UserClass instance based on the ViewModel, and insert the "newuser" into database.
                var newuser = new UserClass();
                newuser.ID = user.ID;
                newuser.Name = user.Name;       
                //save the newuser into the database via dbcontext
                _dbcontext.UserClass.Add(newuser);
                _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View();
        }
   ```
4. Create a CreateUser View page:

   ```
        @model WebApplication2.Models.UserViewModel

        @{
            ViewData["Title"] = "CreateUser";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        } 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form asp-action="CreateUser">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="ID" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsAccepted" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsAccepted)

                        </label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="IsAccepted" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 

        @section Scripts {
            @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
        }
   ```

Then, the screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Hello Zhi, i found [CheckBox Required(Error Message ="Please check the items")] cannot show this message when i miss to click the checkbox. Would you know happened? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers do use validation, it is occuring on server side, to save your users and server a round trip you should also make your ValidationAttribute also implement IClientModelValidator so client side validation can occur.

**Attribute Class**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Attributes {

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public sealed class CheckBoxRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator {

        #region ValidationAttribute Support
        public override bool IsValid(object value) => value is bool thisValue && thisValue;
        #endregion

        #region IClientModelValidator Support
        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context) => context.Attributes.Add("data-val-checkboxrequired", FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()));
        #endregion    

    }
}
```

Then we will create a custom TagHelper do do the work

**TagHelper Class:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp.TagHelpers {
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "validator-unobtrusive-adapter")]
    public class ScriptValidatorUnobtrusiveAdapterTagHelper: TagHelper {

        [HtmlAttributeName(DictionaryAttributePrefix = "bool-validator-")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> BoolValidator { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
            if (output.TagName != "script") {
                throw new ArgumentException(output.TagName + " is not a valid element for " + nameof(ScriptValidatorUnobtrusiveAdapterTagHelper));
            }
            // remove the attributes used to configure tag helper so user cannot see them
            output.Attributes.RemoveAll("validator-unobtrusive-adapter");
            output.Attributes.RemoveAll("bool-validator-");

            // Add in ability for unobtrusive validation on client side
            output.PreContent.AppendHtml("(function ($) {");
            if (this.BoolValidator?.Count > 0) {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in this.BoolValidator) {
                    output.PreContent.AppendFormat("$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool(\"{0}\", \"{1}\");", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
            output.PreContent.AppendHtml("}(jQuery));");
        }
    }
}
```

Then some ViewModel
**ViewModel Example:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Models {
    public class MyViewModel {
        
        [Display(Name = "I accept the terms and conditions.")]
        [CheckBoxRequired(ErrorMessage = " * accept the terms and condition to continue")]
        public bool AcceptedTermsConditions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then somewhere is your view imports
**_ViewImports.cshtml**

```
@addTagHelper *, MyApp
```

Then Finally in your scripts sections make the call to the custom TagHelper to configure the unobtrusive client side validation.
**Scripts Section:**

```
<script validator-unobtrusive-adapter bool-validator-checkboxrequired="required"></script>
```

The taghelper can be expanded to other validators, also it uses the call to Prepend content. This would allow you to acutally put content inside the script calling the tag helper that would appear after the unobtrusive validation content.So it will scale with a little modification to other custom validations. Right now it is just for the bool varient.
** Also forgot to mention (thanks Andy) you need to have the TagHelper namespace referenced in your view calling the taghelper or in your _ViewImports.cshtml.

```
@addTagHelper *, YourExtensionNamespace
```

Comment: This worked great for my. Thanks. Only issue I had was making sure I used the assembly name  in the _ViewImports. In my case I had MyApp.Auth.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a new Attribute class for validating boolean values, which you then place on a new boolean property.

Example Attribute class:

```
public class MustBeTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        if (value is bool b) return b;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only be used on boolean properties.");
    }
}
```

Extend UserClass with a boolean property, including the new Attribute:

```
public class UserClass
{
    // existing properties here

    // new property -->
    [MustBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "You need to accept the terms")]
    public bool Accepted { get; set; }
}
```

Add new elements into the View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Accepted" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Accepted" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Accepted" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Finally, alter your Controller Post action method to check if the model is valid:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(UserClass uc)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(uc);

    _auc.Add(uc);
    _auc.SaveChanges();
    return View(uc);
}
```

*A final note:*
I added the `Accepted` property into class `UserClass`, which you use both for interacting with MVC and for saving into the database.
However, having this new property in your database table may not be desired.
If that is the case then you will need to introduce a `UserModel` class for interacting with MVC (*with* the `Accepted` property) and keep the `UserClass` without the `Accepted` property, and then add code to map from UserClass to UserModel when loading and displaying data + code to map from UserModel to UserClass when data is received from MVC that needs to be saved.

Comment: hello Peter, thanks your advise!!!!! also, i want to konw If (value is boolean b) return b;
What is B mean??thanks!

Comment: `b` is the name of the variable that is implicity created inside the `if()` check, as follows: if `value` is of type `bool`, then `b` is set to `(bool)value`. This is possible since C# 7, for more see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression

Comment: No problem, feel free to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: Hello sir, about final note, my db have two column (Id,name).if I don’t want to insert new column for “accept”. I need to create new model for handle “accept””?thanks

Comment: Yes, as I tried to explain, you will then need two classes: one for saving to/reading from the database (UserClass, or even better name it just **User**). This is also known as the User Entity class. And then one for sending data to/receiving data from MVC (**UserModel**), with data copied back and forth between the two. This is a very common pattern, e.g. see https://cpratt.co/entities-are-not-models/

Comment: @ericso, Peter means you could create a [ViewModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which contains the bool property and the custom validation method, this view model only used to pass data between view and controller and validate the value, after validate success, you could insert the value in the database (using your UserClass model).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and support. i create viewmodel but i don't confirm about Controller logic .would guys help me to check and give advise? coding example below  thanks!

Comment: You should apply the AttributeClass exactly as I did in my code. Just follow my code, and don't do it in other ways that make no sense. AttributeClass certainly should NOT be a property of the ViewModel class. For a walkthrough of creating AND using a custom attribute, here is a tutorial (ignore the music): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lItGxvmZL34

Comment: hello Peter, thank you for your advise and teaching! it is successfully. thank you sooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

i create ViewModel Call UserViewModel

```html
 public class UserViewModel
    {
    //store DB for record
        public UserClass userClass { get; set; }
    //store Attribute class for validating boolean values
        public AttributeClass attributeClass { get; set; }

    }
```

```html
  Controller

    private readonly ApplicationUserClass _auc;
public abcController(ApplicationUserClass auc)
{
    _auc = auc;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public IActionResult Create(UserClass uc)
            {
                UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel() {
                  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return View(uc);

                }
             

                _auc.Add(uc);
                _auc.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }
        }



i don't know how to modify the controller logic. anybody can give advice? thanks
```