# Validation on Checkbox always returns Valid or true in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, attributes

When performing validation for a CheckBox in ASP.NET Core, the resulting `ModelState` always returns `true` both on the client side and when Posting.

I am using the [Required Data Annotation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-8.0) which is not working for Boolean validation specifically validation of the Checked or Unchecked states for a CheckBox in ASP.NET Core.

I have a Razor page with elements bound to the Model class within:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Register.TermsConditions)
@Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Register.TermsConditions, Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.Register.TermsConditions))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Register.TermsConditions, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Here is the part Model class:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Display(Name = "I accept the terms of use.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must accept the terms of use.")]
    public bool TermsConditions { get; set; }
}
```

The Page Model has an async Post handler method that checks the validity of the `ModelState` as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...
        // The ValidationState of the required Checkbox is always Valid even when unchecked
        //...
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return this.LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return this.Page();
}
```

Setting a debugger breakpoint at the source line `if (this.ModelState.IsValid)` reveals this.

[image: Debugger breakpoint on ModelState validation]

How do I setup the [Required] attribute of a boolean property in an ASP.NET Core to perform proper validation and return `true` when Checked and `false` when Unchecked.

Comment: `Required` means it has to be filled out, it doesn't require it to be checked. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711385/make-checkbox-required-with-data-annotations) should answer your question